# NSMutableIndexSet to NSMutableArray

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray, nsindexset

I have ***NSMutableIndexSet*** with indexes, and I want to create a ***NSArray*** with his indexes..

```
NSMutableIndexSet *mutableIndexSet = [NSMutableIndexSet new];
[mutableIndexSet addIndex:0];
[mutableIndexSet addIndex:2];
[mutableIndexSet addIndex:4];
```

how can I do it??

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
[mutableIndexSet enumerateIndexesUsingBlock:^(NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    [myMutableArray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:idx]];
}];
```